# Angular development mode is really slow in Internet Explorer 11 (but fine with newer browsers)

Tags: angular, angular7, internet-explorer-11

I am running an Angular 7.x app which is heavy on textareas & Angular Material that appears to be really slow when using this in Internet Explorer 11. Using modern browsers the app this seems fine including Edge but using Internet Explorer 11 typing in a textarea is seriously laggy and unusable.

In the `main.ts` file if I enable the app to run in production by commenting out the following two lines it runs much much smoother and less lag in IE11.

```
// if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
// }
```

This seems very hacky and wrong as I am 'hacking' the main.ts file - I need to find a solution that will speed up IE11 but this seems like a dirty solution - is there a better way for me to get this benefit? Is there a better way to optimise for IE11?

Comment: mind you show some of your form code ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use F12 dev tools **Performance** tab to analyze which part causes the slow performance in IE. If possible your could make the page lighter as IE doesn't handle programs as well as modern browsers.

You could also refer to [this list](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-performance-checklist) to check if there's any method you can take to speed up the performance. As mentioned in the checklist, [using `enableProdMode`](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-performance-checklist#use-enableprodmode) is indeed a way to optimize the runtime.

Besides, if there's `*ngFor` in your code, please don't forget to [use `trackBy`](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-performance-checklist#use-trackby-option) in it. Also, if `*ngFor` renders a lot of elements, browsers (especially older ones) may slow down and need more time to finish rendering of all elements. To reduce the rendering time, you could refer to the following ways:

> - Apply virtual scrolling via [CDK](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview) or [ngx-virtual-scroller](https://github.com/rintoj/ngx-virtual-scroller)
> - Reducing the amount of DOM elements rendered in `*ngFor` section of your template.
> - Use `ng-container` where possible